# Opening up a webpage inside a div tag instead of a tab

Tags: php

I was wondering if this was possible to do.  I know you can pull a html file and put it on your page like this, `<a href='index.php?content=Contact.html'>` .  Is there someway to pull a webpage from a URL to your site. So instead of a link open in another tab, it would open that webpage on your current site page.  If it's not possible, is there some sort of similar solution I can use.

Comment: Do you mean something like AJAX?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: iframes seems best, and perhaps the most secure. With all of the methods though, be VERY VERY careful, as if the other site becomes malicious, you're open to cross-site scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`iframe`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/iframe) tag to display other web pages inside your own web page.

When you say:

> I know you can pull a html file and put it on your page like this, `<a href='index.php?content=Contact.html'>`

Actually, that's not a normal feature - **it's *only* a function of whatever `index.php` file is on *your server***, and simply displaying content referenced by a GET parameter can actually quite dangerous depending on whether you know what to protect against and how.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how "embedded" in to your site you wish for it to be, but it sounds like you could use **[iframes](http://www.iframehtml.com/)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an external website into your site, have a look at [iframes *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe).

If you want to update parts of the page with content coming from your domain and without refreshing the whole page, you can use [*Ajax*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You can use AJAX to get the other file and then set the .innerHTML property of your div to the loaded content.  In the simplest way, with jQuery you'll have something like this:

```
var data = jQuery.get("http://my.domain.com/file.html")
$('#mydiv').html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.  i would do it something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myDiv').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }
}
```